# Postgresql query to join multiple tables and filter out rows the have multiple entries

Tags: postgresql, networking

I need to create a query that will allow me to join multiple tables as well as remove certain data.

node contains these columns
mac
switch
port
vlan
active
oui

node_ip contains these columns
mac
ip
dns

device contains these columns
ip
dns
name
mac

device_port contains these columns
ip
port
dns

device_port_vlan contains these columns
ip
port
vlan

I need to join this info, then filter out any port that has more than two mac associated with or it the IP has more 1 row.  I'm trying to create a report that shows the name, IP, mac, vlan ,port, and switch a node is connected to.  So i need to discard the ports the more than 2 MACs on them and map the node info to the switch the node is connected to.

SELECT node.mac, node_ip.dns, node.vlan, node.port, node_ip.ip, node.switch, node.time_last
FROM node join node_ip on node.mac = node_ip.mac

"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "1" "1.37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.80"   "2023-03-15 07:20:18.86936"
"80:ac:ac:52:d5:21"     "512"   "1.1"   "10.232.6.1"    "10.232.6.82"   "2023-03-14 09:49:27.50137"
"b4:b5:2f:eb:39:8a"     "512"   "1.1"   "10.232.6.99"   "10.232.6.82"   "2023-03-14 09:49:27.50137"
"00:0c:29:91:61:74"     "0" "1:18"  "42.1.1.10" "10.232.6.62"   "2023-03-15 12:20:20.753191"
"00:0c:29:c3:f3:59"     "0" "1:19"  "43.1.1.10" "10.232.6.62"   "2023-03-15 00:20:17.527459"
"00:0c:29:2f:5d:9b"     "0" "1:20"  "42.1.1.20" "10.232.6.62"   "2023-03-15 00:20:17.527459"
"64:6a:52:ce:29:00"     "4001"  "1.17"  "10.10.40.2"    "10.232.6.76"   "2023-03-14 09:49:38.99056"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "512"   "1.1"   "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.82"   "2023-03-15 10:20:08.140821"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "1" "1.37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.71"   "2023-03-15 15:20:13.619893"
"02:04:96:ae:c6:a1"     "0" "1:43"  "10.232.6.66"   "10.232.6.62"   "2023-03-15 15:20:14.44723"
"02:04:96:ae:c6:a1"     "512"   "1.1"   "10.232.6.66"   "10.232.6.82"   "2023-03-14 09:49:27.50137"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "401"   "1/37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.61"   "2023-03-14 15:20:24.834115"
"02:04:96:ae:c6:a1"     "6" "1.10"  "10.232.6.66"   "10.232.6.76"   "2023-03-14 10:20:07.679493"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "1" "1.37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.69"   "2023-03-15 14:20:08.546483"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "406"   "1.37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.78"   "2023-03-14 15:20:24.598772"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "403"   "1.1"   "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.76"   "2023-03-14 15:20:24.64321"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "0" "1:37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.63"   "2023-03-15 15:20:13.965303"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "1" "2.37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.80"   "2023-03-15 15:20:14.65246"
"00:04:96:ae:b2:a6"     "0" "1:37"  "10.232.6.62"   "10.232.6.64"   "2023-03-15 15:20:14.180816"

Comment: I'm getting closer,  Now I need to figure out how to remove rows if there are more than 2 rows that have the same ip address in the IP column and rows that that have the same switch IP and port number if there are 3 or more that matches that criteria.
If switch = 10.232.6.76 and port = 1.17 on more than 2 rows, remove them all.

Comment: SELECT node.mac, node_ip.ip, device_port_vlan.vlan, node_ip.dns, node.port, node.switch, node.time_last, device.name
        FROM node join node_ip on node.mac = node_ip.mac join device on node.switch = device.ip join device_port_vlan on node.port = device_port_vlan.port
  WHERE device_port_vlan.vlan != '1'
     ORDER BY ip

Comment: "64:6a:52:ce:29:00" "10.10.40.2" 4051  "1.17" "10.232.6.76" "2023-03-14 09:49:38.99056" "C6R27-VSP8400-1"
"64:6a:52:ce:29:00" "10.10.40.2" 4050  "1.17" "10.232.6.76" "2023-03-14 09:49:38.99056" "C6R27-VSP8400-1"
"64:6a:52:ce:29:00" "10.10.40.2" 280  "1.17" "10.232.6.76" "2023-03-14 09:49:38.99056" "C6R27-VSP8400-1"
"00:0c:29:91:61:74" "42.1.1.10" 402  "1:18" "10.232.6.62" "2023-03-15 12:20:20.753191" "C6R13-EXOS-5"
"00:0c:29:2f:5d:9b" "42.1.1.20" 402  "1:20" "10.232.6.62" "2023-03-15 00:20:17.527459" "C6R13-EXOS-5"